# Using bash commands before and after an expect script

Tags: bash, expect

In a nutshell, I am looking to type the name of my script which will have the user prompted for a hostname for the jumpbox, login and password and then the script will run a series of commands such as pinging devices, scp files to other hosts, etc... Currently, I just have the script running a simple ls -lrt.

However, when I run the script everything logs in just fine but then the script ends as soon as I enter the host machine. I am looking to see how to stop the script after log in so that I can then run new commands from the script.

I have looked through a series of pages here and nothing that I have found really talks about this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Logging in to server at HOSTNAME"
echo
echo -n "Hostname:"
read -s host
echo
echo -n "Username:"
read -s user
echo
echo -n "Password:"
read -s PWD
echo

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout 1
spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "password:"
send "$PWD\n"
expect eof


ls -lrt
```

Here are the results I get:

```
Logging in to server at
Username:
Password:
spawn ssh user@host
user@host's password:

-bash-4.1$ home/Desktop:~ userid$
```

The home/Desktop:~ userid$ is the prompt back to my session window outside of the jumpbox.

Comment: The here document has to be terminated by an unindented `EOF`, not `expect eof`. (Case matters.)

Comment: As an aside, it is *much* easier to use public-key authentication than to fool around with `except`. `except` is for tools that truly have no other way to interact with them; `ssh` does, and those methods are more secure than storing your password in plain text in your script.

Comment: As another aside, `PWD` is a reserved variable; don't use it (or any other all-caps variable name) for your own uses.

Comment: Even without public key authentication, there doesn't seem to be any reason for you to ask for the user's password, rather than simply letting `ssh` do it. Run `ssh`, and when it exits (because the use logged out), run `ls -lrt`

Comment: Unless the point was to have `expect` run the `ls -lrt`, in which case I'd just use `ssh user@host 'ls -lrt'` (and yes, you could include a whole script of code in there, but if it's anything more complex, just `scp` a script file and then run *that* remotely with the `ssh`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `expect` doesn't seems correct.
As per your query, you want to scp the files to the remote host, anyways I can help you with the syntax:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn /usr/bin/sftp ${user_name}@${HOSTNAME}
expect "password:"
send "${passwd}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /the_path/to_put_files/\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mput *\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF

ls -lrt
```

---

`set timeout -1` == for sending n number of files to remote server without timeout constraint.

Hope this helps.